# Prefill Database for Phoenix-Application

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I would like to prefill the database of my phoenix project.
When the application is started the first time it should insert some data into the database with initial data like the credentials for an admin account.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I just had the idea using a custom mix task. What do you think? Is this a good idea?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question--define "best".  Best in what way?  Vote to close.

Comment: Okay maybe "best" is not a very good term here. But I don't think using the word "best" is a reason to close the question. I'm sure there are people who want to do simliar things and there is no such question on SO yet.

Comment: It's too broad because you've not even posted a concrete approach that you've tried.  "Is this a good idea?" in reference to using a custom mix task--how could any of us tell? It'd depend--a lot--on the actual code in the custom mix task.  Best approach to add elements into a database the first time an app is run--I can think of three or four answers to that without trying hard. It's too broad.

Comment: I think that you can do that by `mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs`. But I'm not sure how to automate it with first start of the app and why you want it to do that.

Comment: As mentioned above mix scripts like seeds.exs can be used to populate the database, or you could put it as a part of migration. So every time you set up the database with mix ecto.migrate it will also fill the database. It all depends on what you need, but it is a possible approach.